# excecuting vbscript(?) code: automatically open new files in a directory

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, vbscript

im new to vbs-,Powershell-, ... coding

i need to build something that checks for new files in a specific directory and opens all newly added files automatically.

i've found this post which seems to fit my needs perfectly: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-automatically-open-new-files-added-to-a-folder/

I tweaked the code to my situation like this:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject(“Wscript.Shell”)

strComputer = “.”
Set objWMIService = GetObject(“winmgmts:\\” & strComputer & “\root\cimv2”)
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    (“SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE ” _
        & “Targetinstance ISA ‘CIM_DirectoryContainsFile’ and ” _
            & “TargetInstance.GroupComponent= ” _
                & “‘Win32_Directory.Name=””T:\\\\Reporting\\\\AutoOpen””‘”)
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    strNewFile = objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
    arrNewFile = Split(strNewFile, “=”)
    strFileName = arrNewFile(1)
    strFileName = Replace(strFileName, “\\”, “\”)
    strFileName = Replace(strFileName, Chr(34), “”)
    objShell.Run(“excel.exe ” & strFileName)
Loop
```

Bummer that the above post contains no details on how to actually use the code or what programming language it is :D

I assumed this snipped is for vbscript. When i put it in a .vbs file and execute it, i get the error-message "invalid character, line 1, character 29, compiling error, ..." -> this character is the first quotation mark in line 1.

So i also tried powershell, but it seems like the code doesnt fit there either.

... So what kind of code is this after all?
And how can i put it in an executable file?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: The problem is the curly double quotes. MS Word tends to convert standard double quotes to these ones. You have to use the standard `" ` double quote

Comment: This is generally true: Don't just execute some random code from the Internet, ESPECIALLY if you have no idea whatsoever what it is, or does, or how it even works. That's completely reckless. You may run other people's code after you precisely understand each line, not before.

Comment: so true ... o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slanted or *smart quotes* `“.”`  you are using are invalid in vbscript code.

You should replace all of them with regular double quotes `"`

Applications such as MS Word tend to convert regular quotes with these slanted ones, so that might be where you got them from.

Comment: In this case, the curly quotes are likely a feature of the CMS that runs on https://devblogs.microsoft.com. By the looks of it, it's Wordpress. which really likes to "helpfully" insert typographical quotes everywhere it can.

Comment: ok that was an easy fix. i also replaced the ‘ by ' and now it works!
thank you so much for your help.
Greetings from Hamburg, Germany ;)